Android Compose Preview Screenshot Testing on alpha02 and higher not working
I have followed https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/compose-screenshot-testing and can't seem to get any version outside of 0.0.1-alpha01 to work.
With alpha02 and higher I am seeing:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.compose.screenshot', version: '0.0.1-alpha04']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.compose.screenshot'.
   > getValue(...) must not be null

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.InvalidPluginException: An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.compose.screenshot', version: '0.0.1-alpha04']
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.exceptionOccurred(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:179)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.access$400(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:52)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator$ApplyAction.apply(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:160)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$applyPlugins$1(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:130)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:130)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.PluginRequestsHandler.handle(PluginRequestsHandler.kt:45)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator$InterpreterHost.applyPluginsTo(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:220)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$ProgramHost.applyPluginsTo(Interpreter.kt:387)
    at Program.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$ProgramHost.eval(Interpreter.kt:516)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.kt:194)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator.evaluate(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:125)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPluginFactory$create$1.invoke(KotlinScriptPluginFactory.kt:46)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPluginFactory$create$1.invoke(KotlinScriptPluginFactory.kt:43)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPlugin.apply(KotlinScriptPlugin.kt:35)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.code.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:44)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:411)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:429)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:410)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:46)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:27)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:411)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$fromMutableState$2(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:434)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:359)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:434)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:410)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:768)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:158)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.lambda$ensureSelfConfigured$2(ProjectLifecycleController.java:85)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$14(StateTransitionController.java:255)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:254)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning$10(StateTransitionController.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning(StateTransitionController.java:195)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.ensureSelfConfigured(ProjectLifecycleController.java:85)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.ensureConfigured(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:385)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:65)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$prepareProjects$2(VintageBuildModelController.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$14(StateTransitionController.java:255)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:254)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transitionIfNotPreviously$11(StateTransitionController.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transitionIfNotPreviously(StateTransitionController.java:209)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareProjects(VintageBuildModelController.java:84)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.getConfiguredModel(VintageBuildModelController.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$withProjectsConfigured$1(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:133)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$notInState$3(StateTransitionController.java:132)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.notInState(StateTransitionController.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.withProjectsConfigured(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:133)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildToolingModelController.locateBuilderForTarget(DefaultBuildToolingModelController.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.lambda$locateBuilderForTarget$0(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.withToolingModels(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:327)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.AbstractBuildState.withToolingModels(AbstractBuildState.java:160)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.locateBuilderForTarget(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.locateBuilderForDefaultTarget(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getTarget(DefaultBuildController.java:140)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:111)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:116)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:79)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:32)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.lambda$initAction$6(GradleModelFetchAction.java:184)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.telemetry.GradleOpenTelemetry.callWithSpan(GradleOpenTelemetry.java:73)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.telemetry.GradleOpenTelemetry.callWithSpan(GradleOpenTelemetry.java:61)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.initAction(GradleModelFetchAction.java:183)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.doExecute(GradleModelFetchAction.java:138)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.lambda$execute$1(GradleModelFetchAction.java:103)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.telemetry.GradleOpenTelemetry.callWithSpan(GradleOpenTelemetry.java:73)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.telemetry.GradleOpenTelemetry.callWithSpan(GradleOpenTelemetry.java:61)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.lambda$execute$2(GradleModelFetchAction.java:102)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.withOpenTelemetry(GradleModelFetchAction.java:113)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.lambda$execute$3(GradleModelFetchAction.java:101)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.util.GradleExecutorServiceUtil.withSingleThreadExecutor(GradleExecutorServiceUtil.java:18)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.execute(GradleModelFetchAction.java:100)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.execute(GradleModelFetchAction.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:65)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.executeAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:109)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:97)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.beforeTasks(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:81)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.beforeTasks(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$fromBuildModel$2(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:83)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:120)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$7(StateTransitionController.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:117)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:140)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:54)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:130)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.execute(InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitProblems.execute(InitProblems.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:209)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:263)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:127)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.StartParamsValidatingActionExecutor.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.StartParamsValidatingActionExecutor.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecutor.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.SessionFailureReportingActionExecutor.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.SessionFailureReportingActionExecutor.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecutor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.SetupLoggingActionExecutor.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecutor.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.SetupLoggingActionExecutor.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.lambda$execute$0(ForwardClientInput.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.daemon.clientinput.ClientInputForwarder.forwardInput(ClientInputForwarder.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.lambda$runCommand$0(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:321)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.compose.screenshot'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.resolve.internal.ArtifactRepositoriesPluginResolver$ExternalPluginResolution.applyTo(ArtifactRepositoriesPluginResolver.java:151)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator$ApplyAction.apply(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:156)
    ... 194 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: getValue(...) must not be null
    at com.android.compose.screenshot.PreviewScreenshotGradlePlugin$Companion.getSCREENSHOT_TEST_PLUGIN_VERSION(PreviewScreenshotGradlePlugin.kt:94)
    at com.android.compose.screenshot.PreviewScreenshotGradlePlugin$apply$1.execute(PreviewScreenshotGradlePlugin.kt:139)
    at com.android.compose.screenshot.PreviewScreenshotGradlePlugin$apply$1.execute(PreviewScreenshotGradlePlugin.kt:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.code.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.collections.CollectionFilter$1.execute(CollectionFilter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:161)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.withType(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:203)
    at com.android.compose.screenshot.PreviewScreenshotGradlePlugin.apply(PreviewScreenshotGradlePlugin.kt:106)
    at com.android.compose.screenshot.PreviewScreenshotGradlePlugin.apply(PreviewScreenshotGradlePlugin.kt:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginTarget.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginTarget.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ModelDefaultsApplyingPluginTarget.applyImperative(ModelDefaultsApplyingPluginTarget.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:190)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.access$100(DefaultPluginManager.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager$AddPluginBuildOperation.run(DefaultPluginManager.java:288)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.lambda$doApply$0(DefaultPluginManager.java:170)
    at org.gradle.internal.code.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:169)
    ... 197 more

Setup:

Android Studio Preveiew (Ladybug 2024.2.1 Canary 7)
Gradlw Wrapper 8.10
AGP 8.6.0-rc01

Any help welcome.

I wanted to capture this in case it helps someone else in the future.  So, after many weeks of tinkering with alpha02 - alpha07, I finally have been able to update to the latest alpha07.  In my libs.versions.toml, I have:
[versions]
com-android-compose-screenshot = "0.0.1-alpha07"


[libraries]
com-android-compose-screenshot-gradle-plugin = { module = "com.android.compose.screenshot:com.android.compose.screenshot.gradle.plugin", version.ref = "com-android-compose-screenshot" }

[plugins]
com-android-compose-screenshot = { id = "com.android.compose.screenshot", version.ref = "com-android-compose-screenshot" }

And in my module build.gradle I have:
plugins {
    // Other plugins applied

    id(libs.plugins.com.android.compose.screenshot.get().pluginId)
}

I am using the plugin id here because of what I will mention below (having to have the plugin already on the classpath with a version).
Not sure why, but I took a wild stab/guess and everything worked when I added this to the project level build.gradle:
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath(libs.com.android.compose.screenshot.gradle.plugin)
    }
}

Really bizarre how the getSCREENSHOT_TEST_PLUGIN_VERSION was null until I added the library on the classpath in this way.
There may be a better way to fix and adjust this, but for now, I'm finally able to do screenshot testing with my app's custom theme which is what was driving my want to update.

did you post a issue on the issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:1581441 for this. Since its still in active development and a alpha version all bugs should be posted there so that they can be fixed.

Unfortunately I haven't been able to since I am not allowed to create issues for the Compose Preview Screenshot component.  I would love to make sure this is on their radar though.  Any suggestions for how to create an issue with them that targets this library?

just create a generic on the tracker and add a reply mentioning that its an issue for component 1581441

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/368205258 Thanks!
